# Xcode Incorrectly Reporting Swift Access Race Condition

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, race-condition, ios-multithreading

I believe XCode is incorrectly reporting Swift Access Race in my `SynchronizedDictionary` - or is it?

My `SynchronizedDictionary` looks like this:

```
public struct SynchronizedDictionary<K: Hashable, V> {
    private var dictionary = [K: V]()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "SynchronizedDictionary",
        qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated,
        attributes: [DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent]
    )

    public subscript(key: K) -> V? {
        get {
            return queue.sync {
                return self.dictionary[key]
            }
        }
        mutating set {
            queue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
                self.dictionary[key] = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following test code will trigger a "Swift Access Race" issue (when the Thread Sanitizer is turned on for the scheme):

```
var syncDict = SynchronizedDictionary<String, String>()

let setExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "set_expectation")
let getExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "get_expectation")

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "SyncDictTest", qos: .background, attributes: [.concurrent])

queue.async {
    for i in 0...100 {
        syncDict["\(i)"] = "\(i)"
    }
    setExpectation.fulfill()
}

queue.async {
    for i in 0...100 {
        _ = syncDict["\(i)"]
    }
    getExpectation.fulfill()
}

self.wait(for: [setExpectation, getExpectation], timeout: 30)
```

The Swift Race Access look like this:

[image: Swift Race Access]
I really did not expect there to be an access race condition here, because the `SynchronizedDictionary` should handle the concurrency.

I can fix the issue by, in the test, wrapping the getting and setting in a DispatchQueue similar to the actual implementation of the `SynchronizedDictionary`:

```
let accessQueue = DispatchQueue(
    label: "AccessQueue",
    qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated,
    attributes: [DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent]
)

var syncDict = SynchronizedDictionary<String, String>()

let setExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "set_expectation")
let getExpectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "get_expectation")

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "SyncDictTest", qos: .background, attributes: [.concurrent])

queue.async {
    for i in 0...100 {
        accessQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
            syncDict["\(i)"] = "\(i)"
        }
    }
    setExpectation.fulfill()
}

queue.async {
    for i in 0...100 {
        accessQueue.sync {
            _ = syncDict["\(i)"]
        }
    }
    getExpectation.fulfill()
}

self.wait(for: [setExpectation, getExpectation], timeout: 30)
```

...but that already happens inside the `SynchronizedDictionary` - so why is Xcode reporting an Access Race Condition? - is Xcode at fault, or am I missing something?

Comment: Your 2 async blocks can be assigned to different threads controlled by your concurrent queue.  Either of those threads could execute first.  I suspect it's therefore complaining that the code doesn't guarantee the setter will run before the getter.  You can test my theory by making it a serial queue and seeing whether the error goes away.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I agree with you, that replacing the concurrent queue with a serial will fix the issue. However, that defies the purpose of the SynchronizedDictionary - being able to access it concurrently.

Comment: @PhillipMills In the end, both the setter and getter goes into the concurrent queue and the setter blocks everything. I don't see how this results in a race conditions when everything is blocked and waits for the setter to complete.

Comment: @PelleStenildColtau: Note that in the setter you can dispatch *asynchronously* (with a barrier), see for example https://medium.com/@oyalhi/dispatch-barriers-in-swift-3-6c4a295215d6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread sanitizer reports a [Swift access race](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/thread_sanitizer/swift_access_races) to the

```
var syncDict = SynchronizedDictionary<String, String>()
```

structure, because there is a mutating access (via the subscript setter) at

```
syncDict["\(i)"] = "\(i)"
```

from one thread, and a read-only access to the same structure (via the subscript getter) at

```
_ = syncDict["\(i)"]
```

from a different thread, without synchronization.

This has nothing to do with conflicting access to the `private var dictionary` property, or with what happens *inside* the subscript methods at all. You'll get the same “Swift access race” if you simplify the structure to

```
public struct SynchronizedDictionary<K: Hashable, V> {
    private let dummy = 1

    public subscript(key: String) -> String {
        get {
            return key
        }
        set {
        }
    }
}
```

So this is a *correct* report from the thread sanitizer, not a bug.

A possible solution would be to define a *class* instead:

```
public class SynchronizedDictionary<K: Hashable, V> { ... }
```

That is a reference type and the subscript setter no longer mutates the `syncDict` variable (which is now a “pointer” into the actual object storage). With that change, your code runs without errors.

Comment: Ah so it's a race condition to the variable `syncDict` and this has nothing to do with whatever is inside the `syncDict` at all :)

Comment: @MartinR, I recently had this issue, and although I changed my SynchorizedDictionary to a class I don't fully understand why it worked. I decided to google it and then I stumbled upon your answer. I understand that the getter and setter can be accessed from different threads but the body of those are synchronized. So I don't understand why XCode is complaining about it and why I occasionally saw crashes at run time.