# Why does my SynchronizedDictionary only crash when it is a struct?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronized

I have the following `SynchronizedDictionary`:

```
public struct SynchronizedDictionary<K: Hashable, V> {
    private var dictionary = [K: V]()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "SynchronizedDictionary",
        attributes: [DispatchQueue.Attributes.concurrent]
    )

    public subscript(key: K) -> V? {
        get {
            return queue.sync {
                return self.dictionary[key]
            }
        }
        mutating set {
            queue.sync(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.barrier) {
                self.dictionary[key] = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    mutating func removeAll() {
        queue.sync(flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags.barrier) {
            self.dictionary.removeAll()
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following code, that is designed to test the concurrency of `SynchronizedDictionary`. The code will concurrently make read and writes to the dictionary (twice as many reads as writes).

```
let list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]

var dict = SynchronizedDictionary<String, String>()

let queue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "test", attributes: .concurrent)

for value in 1...1000 {
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: value.description)
    queue.async {
        let element = list.randomElement()!
        if [1, 2, 3].randomElement()! == 1 {
            print("writing \(element)")
            dict[element] = UUID().uuidString
        } else {
            print("reading \(element)")
            _ = dict[element]
        }

        expectation.fulfill()
    }
}
self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
```

My problem is that my test crashes with the following stack trace:

```
...
writing 3
reading 5
reading 2
writing 4
reading 1
2019-09-20 11:13:08.836133+0200 TestApp[39907:2053064] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b7ff29b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109e43735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b81dfa4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b803fb6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b805e88 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010a81074c $sSD8_VariantVyq_Sgxcig + 140
    6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010aa3c599 $sSDyq_Sgxcig + 9
    7   MyApp                               0x00000001216abd1e $s8MyApp22SynchronizedDictionaryVyq_SgxcigADyXEfU_ + 206
    8   MyApp                               0x00000001216abdca $s8MyApp22SynchronizedDictionaryVyq_SgxcigADyXEfU_TA + 58
    9   libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae53941 $sxs5Error_pIgrzo_xsAA_pIegrzo_lTRTA + 17
    10  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae4cec2 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8DispatchE11_syncHelper33_F417D752D2C4E9330E1C700411CE0C6ALL2fn7execute6rescuexyyyXEXE_xyKXExs5Error_pKXEtKlFyxyKcXEfU_yyXEfU_ + 82
    11  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae539bd $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8DispatchE11_syncHelper33_F417D752D2C4E9330E1C700411CE0C6ALL2fn5flags7execute6rescuexyAC0D8WorkItemCXE_AC0dtU5FlagsVxyKXExs5Error_pKXEtKlFyyXEfU_TATm + 29
    12  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae53990 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8DispatchE11_syncHelper33_F417D752D2C4E9330E1C700411CE0C6ALL2fn7execute6rescuexyyyXEXE_xyKXExs5Error_pKXEtKlFyxyKcXEfU_yyXEfU_TA + 16
    13  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae53741 $sIg_Ieg_TRTA + 17
    14  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae54a19 $sIg_Ieg_TRTA.139 + 9
    15  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae46e5e $sIeg_IyB_TR + 14
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc13587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc20366 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete_recurse + 97
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc1fde5 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 225
    19  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae4d478 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC4sync7executeyyyXE_tFTO + 152
    20  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae51510 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC4sync7executeyyyXE_tFTOTA + 16
    21  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae4cd73 $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8DispatchE11_syncHelper33_F417D752D2C4E9330E1C700411CE0C6ALL2fn7execute6rescuexyyyXEXE_xyKXExs5Error_pKXEtKlF + 259
    22  libswiftDispatch.dylib              0x000000010ae4d3af $sSo17OS_dispatch_queueC8DispatchE4sync7executexxyKXE_tKlF + 143
    23  MyApp                               0x00000001216abbf8 $s8MyApp22SynchronizedDictionaryVyq_Sgxcig + 376
    24  MyAppTests                          0x0000000120733ace $s13MyAppTests26SynchronizedDictionarySpecC4specyyFyyXEfU_yyXEfU_yycfU_yycfU_ + 2286
    25  MyAppTests                          0x0000000120733f95 $s13MyAppTests26SynchronizedDictionarySpecC4specyyFyyXEfU_yyXEfU_yycfU_yycfU_TA + 21
    26  MyAppTests                          0x0000000120733bbd $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc1251d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc13587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc15fac _dispatch_continuation_pop + 453
    30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc15619 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 827
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc224af _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 355
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cc22d19 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 97
    33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010cffb6b3 _pthread_wqthread + 583
    34  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010cffb3fd start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

If I change the `SynchronizedDictionary` to a class, the test runs fine!

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: If you enable the thread sanitizer then it will report a "Swift Access Race" – therefore I assume that it is the same issue as in your previous question [Xcode Incorrectly Reporting Swift Access Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54998659/1187415).

Comment: Good catch! You are probably right!